# What is the valid range of this formula?

Tags: complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

Let consider the Gaussian integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \,e^{-\frac{1}{2}a\,x^2}=\sqrt\frac{2\pi}{a},\tag{1}$$
where $x$ is a real variable and $a$ is a positive real number. Now I would like to know, if I let $a$ to be complex, what is the valid range of this equality beyond which I need to do the analytical continuation? If possible, please show also the poles or branch cut singularities because of which equality (1) becomes invalid. Thank you very much.

Comment: A remark: The integral on the left-hand side is only convergent (in the standard sense) for $\Re a > 0$, so extending the formula beyond this region will require a clear definition of what you mean by the left hand side.

Comment: Yes, if $Re\ a<0$, then the integral diverges, so we may need to do the continuation as we do for the Riemann zeta function?

Comment: you should add the range of integration

Comment: $f(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \,e^{-\frac{1}{2}a\,x^2}dx$ is complex analytic for $Re(a) > 0$, $g(a) =(2\pi)^{1/2} a^{-1/2}$ is complex analytic for $Re(a) > 0$, and for $a \in (0,\infty)$ : $f(a) = g(a)$. Hence by the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement) $f(a) = g(a)$ stays true for $Re(a) > 0$